# Adding Web App to WebSphere Liberty Profile via Eclipse plugin tools

Tags: spring, jsf-2, eclipse-plugin, websphere, websphere-liberty

I'm attempting to get an existing web application working with 'WebSphere Application Server Liberty Profile v8.5 Beta' using the 'IBM WebSphere Liberty Profile Tools for Eclipse'.

I have installed the developer tools for Eclipse as well as the liberty profile runtime by following instructions here:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/wasdev/entry/download?lang=en#comment-1321558450546

I then proceed to create the Liberty Profile Server by following the instructions here:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/beta/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.w4d.nd.doc%2Ftopics%2Frw4d_dirs.html

I add my web app to the server and start it with the following console output:

```
Launching TEST (was4d-1.0.0.20111202-0614/websphere-kernel_1.0.0) on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, version 1.6.0_26-b03
    Boot properties: file:/home/tbuckley/work/WAS/was4d/usr/servers/TEST/bootstrap.properties
    Config document: file:/home/tbuckley/work/WAS/was4d/usr/servers/TEST/server.xml
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0001I: The kernel was launched.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0002I: The kernel started after 0.91
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0007I: A feature update is starting after 0.92 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0058I: Application monitor started after 1.218 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKO0219I: TCP Channel http-default has been started and is now listening for requests on host localhost  (IPv4: 127.0.0.1) port 9080.
[AUDIT   ] SRVE9998A: Application myWebApp added to web container.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: The application myWebApp has started successfully.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0008I: The feature update is complete after 2.141 seconds.
```

When I hit the web app url http://localhost:9080/myWebApp/ via a browser I get a blank page and the following console info:

```
[ERROR   ] SRVE0015E: Failure to initialize Web application myWebApp
```

If I reload the page I get the following:

```
[WARNING ] SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for path-->/login/*, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[Application Servlet:[/login/*]], application-->myWebApp.
[ERROR   ] SRVE0015E: Failure to initialize Web application myWebApp
```

I also have the following servlets/mappings under my web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Application Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Any ideas what could be wrong here or how I could get more detailed debug info?

### UPDATE

I just created a skeleton 'dynamic web project' there and put an index.html file in it. I added it to the liberty server and it worked by going to localhost:9080/simpleApp/index.html.

The exisiting dynamic web app I am trying to add is very large and complex.
I found the following under was4d/usr/servers/TEST/logs/ffdc/ffdc_12.02.16_16.40.33.0.log:

```
------Start of DE processing------ = 16/02/12 16:36:06:170 GMT, key = java.lang.NullPointerException com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer 131
Exception = java.lang.NullPointerException
Source = com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer
probeid = 131
S    tack Dump = java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:142)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initializeServletContainerInitializers(WebApp.java:1860)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:499)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:5437)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer.discriminate(WebContainer.java:1095)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer.discriminate(WebContainer.java:1009)
at com.ibm.ws.dispatcher.http.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready(HttpDispatcherLink.java:143)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:444)
a    t com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:378)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:278)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:249)
at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:174)
at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:83)
at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:502)
at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:550)
at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:899)
at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:981)
at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.executeWork(Worker.java:398)
at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.run(Worker.java:380)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

The spring setup in the web app appears to be causing some issue?

Thanks

Comment: @bkail, are you sure that "wlp" is the best possible tag spelling?  Acronyms are hard to find.

Comment: @Charlies No, I'm not sure :-).  I'm fine with any alternatives.  Maybe websphere-liberty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it is an issue with Spring on certain platforms (WebSphere liberty 8.5 in my case).

Upgrading from Spring 3.1.0 M2 to Spring 3.1.1 fixes the issue:
https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8496